# How to access managed bean and session bean from Servlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

Here is how my `commandLink` work

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{myBean.users}" var="item">
     <p:column>
         <h:commandLink value="#{item.name}" action="#{myBean.setSelectedUser(item)}" />     
     </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

then in `myBean.java`

```
 public String setSelectedUser(User user){
     this.selectedUser = user;
     return "Profile";
 }
```

Let assume the user name is `Peter`. Then if I click on `Peter`, I will set the `selectedUser` to be Peter's User Object, then redirect to the profile page, which now render information from `selectedUser`. I want to create that same effect only using `<h:outputText>`, so GET request come to mind. So I do this

```
 <h:outputText value="{myBean.text(item.name,item.id)}" />
```

then the `text(String name, Long id)` method just return

```
"<a href=\"someURL?userId=\"" + id + ">" + name + "</a>"
```

all that left is creating a servlet, catch that `id`, query the database to get the `user` object, set to `selectedUser`, the redirect. 
So here is my servlet

```
public class myServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Long userId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("userId"));
    }
}
```

Now I have the `id`, how do I access my session bean to query the database for the `user`, then access managed bean to set the `user` to `selectedUser`, then redirect to `profile.jsf`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JSF stores session scoped managed beans as session attribute using managed bean name as key.  So the following should work (assuming that JSF has already created the bean before in the session):

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("myBean");
```

That said, I have the feeling that you're looking in the wrong direction for the solution. You could also just do like follows:

```
<a href="profile.jsf?userId=123">
```

with the following in a request scoped bean associated with `profile.jsf`

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.userId}")
private Long userId;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}")
private SessionBean sessionBean;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    sessionBean.setUser(em.find(User.class, userId));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For the `SessionBean`, dont u have to inject @EJB annotation?

Comment: Can also. That was not clear from the question :) It's just a kickoff example how to make use of `@ManagedProperty` and `@PostConstruct` to apply and process request parameters.

Comment: I am sorry, but this might be a stupid question. The way I associate the `jsf` file with the managed bean is basically just calling the method of the bean via `EL`. The bean for `profile.jsf` is session scoped. I know I need a request/view scoped bean, but now I dont know how to associate that bean to `profile.jsf`. `init()` method never get call.

Comment: Just reference it somewhere in the view. E.g. `Welcome, #{bean.sessionBean.user.name}`.

Comment: Thank you. It work with the requestScoped, but with viewScoped, it generate the error, `The scope of the object referenced by expression #{param.userId}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (Profile) scope of view`. Thank you BalusC

Comment: JSF is right, I removed the viewscope suggestion :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the parameter from the URL in the ViewScoped, or you must do it in RequestScoped like what you suggest above? It seems like it a bit too restricted if JSF only allow to do it in RequestScoped bean.

Comment: never mind, I can get it via getRequestParameterMap().

Answer (score 4):

You can add **Inject** and **EJB** annotations in servlet's fields if your are using a Java EE 6 Application Server like Glassfish v3. Some like this:

```
@Inject
private AppManagedBean appmanaged;
@EJB
private SessionBean sessbean;
```

Remeber, those annotations are part of *Context and Dependecy Injection* or **CDI**, so, you must add the **beans.xml** deployment descriptor.

But, if you can't use the **CDI** annotations, lookup for the **BeanManager** interface at **java:comp/BeanManager** and use it for access (only) **managed beans** (inside a managed bean you can inject **session beans** with **@EJB** annotation). Also remember to add the **beans.xml** deployment descriptor.

Utility class looking up for **java:comp/BeanManager**:

```
package mavenproject4;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ManagedBeans {

    private static final BeanManager beanManager;

    static {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            beanManager = (BeanManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    private ManagedBeans() {
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(name);
        Bean<? extends Object> resolve = beanManager.resolve(beans);
        CreationalContext<? extends Object> createCreationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(resolve);
        return (T) beanManager.getReference(resolve, clazz, createCreationalContext);
    }
}
```

Usage of utility class in servlet's **processRequest** method or equivalent:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

AppManagedBean appmanaged = ManagedBeans.getBean(AppManagedBean.class, "app");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet BeanManager</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>" + appmanaged.getHelloWorld() + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Example of **managed bean** with injected **session bean**:

```
package mavenproject4;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("app")
public class AppManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private int counter = 0;
    @EJB
    private SessionBean sessbean;

    public AppManagedBean() {
    }

    public String getHelloWorld() {
        counter++;
        return "Hello World " + counter + " times from Pachuca, Hidalgo, Mexico!";
    }
}
```

I don't know if the code in utility class is 100% correct, but works. Also the code doesn't check *NullPointerException and friends*.