# Accessing JSF session scoped bean from servlet which is called by applet embedded in JSF webapp

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, applet, managed-bean

I need to access a session scoped bean from a servlet. I already tried

```
UserBean userBean = (UserBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("userBean");
```

as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920184/1644061). But I only get null as result, altough an instance of UserBean is alreay instatiated. Those are the annotations/imports I use for userBean :

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
 ... }
```

Some Background why I can't get rid of the servlet : I have a file upload applet in my jsf page. This applet expects an adress where it can send it's POST request. (I can't edit this post request to add more fields or something). The post method of my servlet then stores the file. This job can't be done by a managed bean because the servlet has to be annotated with @MultiPartConfig and I can't add this annotation to the jsf managed bean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it returns `null`, then it can only mean 2 things:

1. JSF hasn't created the bean beforehand yet.
2. The applet-servlet interaction doesn't use the same HTTP session as the webapp.

Given the way how you described the functional requirement, I think it's the latter. You need to ensure that you pass the session identifier of the webapp along with the HTTP request from the applet as well. This can be in the form of the `JSESSIONID` cookie or the `jsessionid` URL path attribute.

First, you need to tell the applet about the session ID the webapp is using. You can do it by passing a parameter to `<applet>` or `<object>` tag holding the applet

```html
<param name="sessionId" value="#{session.id}" />
```

*(the `#{session}` is an implicit JSF EL variable referring the current [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) which in turn has a `getId()` method; you don't need to create a managed bean for that or so, the above line of code is complete as-is)*

which can be retrieved in the applet as follows:

```
String sessionId = getParameter("sessionId");
```

You didn't describe how you're interacting with the servlet, but assuming that you're using the [standard Java SE `URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/) for this, pointing to the `@WebServlet("/servleturl")` servlet, then you can use `setRequestProperty()` to set a request header:

```
URL servlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "servleturl");
URLConnection connection = servlet.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
// ...
```

Alternatively, you can also pass it as a URL path attribute:

```
URL servlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "servleturl;jsessionid=" + sessionId);
URLConnection connection = servlet.openConnection();
// ...
```

*(please note that the case matters in the both cases)*

Either way, this way the applet-servlet interaction will take place in the same HTTP session as JSF managed beans.

Comment: Hm since the applet is a third party applet (JUpload) I would prefer not to edit its source code. I'll look for a parameter to keep the same Session id , I think I remember there is one. Thanks again for your help ;-)

Comment: Ah, likely there's a parameter taking the upload target URL? You could then inline the session ID as path fragment. E.g. `<param name="some" value="servleturl;jsessionid=#{session.id}" />`

Comment: Yes there is a parameter "postURL" which I use. I'll then just append the session id to that call :-)

Comment: hey Balus, I now have a ViewScoped Bean where I store some form input data which I want to use in the servlet which handles the file upload request. Is it possible to access the ViewScoped bean from within the servlet ? If I change the scope into SessionScope I am able to process the input but with ViewScoped I get a NullPointerException if I try to access the bean like this : UploadBean uploadBean = (UploadBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("uploadBean");

Comment: Press `Ask Question` button.