# Java Applet seems to use old response object when given jsession id

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, applet

I have a file upload applet in my jsf page. This applet expects an adress where it can send it's POST request. (I can't edit this post request to add more fields or something). The post method of my servlet then stores the file. This job can't be done by a managed bean because the servlet has to be annotated with @MultiPartConfig and I can't add this annotation to the jsf managed bean. In order to force the upload applet to use the same session I added an URL attribute named jsessionId to the post request according to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194034/accessing-jsf-session-scoped-bean-from-servlet-which-is-called-by-applet-embedde). Now whenever I try to upload more than one file during a session the applet stops with the error message "The regexp string "^SUCCESS$" was not found in the response body" this is because the applet expects this string in the servlets response in order to know that the upload was successfull.

When I view the debug code of the applet the response contains a lot of html code but not this success string altough I add it in my Servlet code. Here's the code of my servlet :

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.reset();
    if (!userBean.getUploadedDatasets().isEmpty()) {
        String datasetID = userBean.getUploadedDatasets().getLast().replaceAll("/", "%2F");
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("http://____________/faces/details.xhtml?id="+datasetID));
    }
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        Part filePart = request.getPart("item");
        InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
        String datasetID = repBean.persistDataset(filecontent, uploadBean.getFolder());
        userBean.getUploadedDatasets().add(datasetID);
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("SUCCESS");
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequestHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequestHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        out.close();
    }
}
```

the doGet method is used as afterUploadURL by the applet (so that's the url to which is jumped after a file is uploaded)

the applet code is :

```
          <APPLET
           CODE="wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet"
           NAME="JUpload"
           ARCHIVE="wjhk.jupload.jar"
           WIDTH="640"
           HEIGHT="300"
           MAYSCRIPT="true"
           ALT="The java pugin must be installed.">
           <param name="postURL" value="http://________________/request;jsessionid=#{session.id}" />
           <!-- Optionnal, see code comments -->
           <param name="showLogWindow" value="false" />
           <param name="debugLevel" value="99" />
           <param name="httpUploadParameterName" value="item" />
           <param name="nbFilesPerRequest" value="1" />
           <param name="httpUploadParameterType" value="oneFile" />
           <param name="afterUploadURL" value="http://________________/request" />
          </APPLET>
```

and after trying to upload a second file, the "old" (that's what I think but I don't know enough about servlets) response looks like this : http://pastebin.ca/2300999
(too many characters so I had to upload it there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused because the servlet is sending a redirect on GET (and implicitly also HEAD) request. The following part of the log contains relevant information:

```
00064   13:44:42.482      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Getting serverProtocol from HEAD request
00065   13:44:42.485      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Checking protocol with URL: http://___________________:8080/application1/request;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33
00066   13:44:42.501      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [initByteArrayEncoder] proxy=DIRECT, proxy.type=DIRECT, useProxy=false, url.host=___________________, url.port=8080
00067   13:44:42.501      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [onAppendHeader] Start
00068   13:44:42.502      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [onAppendHeader] Header appended; Cookie: __utma=132868616.170774110.1354796930.1356109339.1356547898.3; __utmz=132868616.1356547898.3.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
00069   13:44:42.509      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [onAppendHeader] Header appended; User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
00070   13:44:42.510      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [onAppendHeader] End
00071   13:44:42.510      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      [HTTPConnectionHelper append]
00072   13:44:42.511      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Before sendRequest()
00073   13:44:42.511      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Using non SSL socket, direct connection
00074   13:44:42.538      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      After sendRequest()
00075   13:44:42.538      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
00076   13:44:42.538      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -----------------   HEAD message sent (start)  --------------------------
00077   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      HEAD /application1/request;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33 HTTP/1.1
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Host: ___________________:8080
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Accept: */*
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Accept-Encoding: identity
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Connection: close
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Cookie: __utma=132868616.170774110.1354796930.1356109339.1356547898.3; __utmz=132868616.1356547898.3.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
00078   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      
00079   13:44:42.539      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
00080   13:44:42.540      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -----------------   HEAD message sent (end) -----------------------------
00081   13:44:42.540      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
00082   13:44:42.548      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      -------- Response Headers Start --------
00083   13:44:42.556      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
00084   13:44:42.558      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Location: http://___________________:8080/application1/faces/details.xhtml;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33?id=%2F37ded64f-f2c9-4b90-99ea-79c34eb140e5
00085   13:44:42.559      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
00086   13:44:42.566      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Content-Language: de-DE
00087   13:44:42.578      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Content-Length: 306
00088   13:44:42.578      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 12:44:42 GMT
00089   13:44:42.579      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Connection: close
00090   13:44:42.579      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      
00091   13:44:42.580      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      --------- Response Headers End ---------
00092   13:44:42.580      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      This is a HEAD request: we don't care about the bytearrayResponseBody
00093   13:44:42.584      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      HEAD status: 302
00094   13:44:42.585      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      HEAD protocol: HTTP/1.1
00095   13:44:42.586      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [DEBUG]      Location read: http://___________________:8080/application1/faces/details.xhtml;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33?id=%2F37ded64f-f2c9-4b90-99ea-79c34eb140e5
00096   13:44:42.594      HttpProtocolFinderThread     [INFO]       postURL switched from http://___________________:8080/application1/request;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33 to http://___________________:8080/application1/faces/details.xhtml;jsessionid=47440f88e532021656b3724eea33?id=%2F37ded64f-f2c9-4b90-99ea-79c34eb140e5
```

The applet is basically testing the availability of `postURL` by a HEAD request and once determined that it's been redirected, it's using the redirected URL as new `postURL` (as per the last line of the copypasted log). However, the redirected URL is pointing to a JSF page which returns a whole bunch of HTML.

You need to fix your `doGet()` that it doesn't perform a redirect, or to add a `doHead()` which returns effectively nothing. As a HEAD is per the HTTP specification basically a GET without a response body, the default `doHead()` implementation delegates to the `doGet()` and discards the response body. Overriding the `doHead()` should prevent it from delegating to `doGet()`.