# Set values for Managed Beans in a servlet filter.

Tags: java, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have this case:
I want to save the user name in a session scoped managed bean after a successful login. I do that login in a servlet filter. How can I access the managed bean from a servlet filter?

Comment: you set filter no user out of scope. Then ok problem arise. Bean value.

Comment: No context, no examples, poor quality! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and aftewards have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920069/how-to-access-managed-bean-and-session-bean-from-servlet)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a JSF managedBean from a Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578622/accessing-a-jsf-managedbean-from-a-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question right, you want to access your beans from a servlet. You should be able to access them in the Servlet Context, [look at this answer to see how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578724/1073063).